# formatar moeda em span dinamico

Tags: javascript, html

Quero formatar um resultado dinâmico de um input type range, que me dá um valor dinâmico em um span. Preciso formatar esse valor para moeda. Ex: 1000 para 1.000

html

```
<span id="exibePercent">1000</span>

<input style="width:200px;" type="range" class="custom-range" min="1000" max="25000" id="price" value="1000" oninput="getElementById('exibePercent').innerHTML = this.value">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode formatar o valor para currency com a funcao **toLocaleString()** que está presente na classe ou alias int do javascript.

```js
var valor = 55;
valor = valor.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style :"currency", currency : 'BRL'});
//output: "R$ 55,00"
```

Caso seja preciso formatar apenas os para número formatado sem **R$**, Basta remover os parâmetros da função

```js
var valor = 55555;
valor = valor.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
//output: "55.555,00"
```

No seu caso acima ficaria

```html
<input style="width:200px;" type="range" class="custom-range" min="1000" max="25000" id="price" value="1000" oninput="getElementById('exibePercent').innerHTML = parseInt(this.value).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style :'currency', currency : 'BRL'})"
```